# how to grab data from json and create new form send to api in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to submit a form group in angular2 but My data don't want to user to fill in. I want to get data from Json data which I get from the backend API through the GET method. But How I can Use the data in the new from group which I want to submit to the backend API. I want to warp rfidCode and username in to new form.

```
<div class="container-fiuld">
  <form [formGroup]="searchuserform" (ngSubmit)="onSearchUser()">
    <div class="form-content">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usernames">username</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
               id="usernames"
               name="usernames"
               formControlName="usernames"
               >
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"class="btn rounded-btn"> search </button>
  </form>
  <form [formGroup]="searchtoolform" (ngSubmit)="onSearchTool()">
    <div class="form-content">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rfidCode">tool</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
               id="rfidCode"
               name="rfidCode"
               formControlName="rfidCode"
               >
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"class="btn rounded-btn"> search </button>
  </form>

  <div class="user-card">
    <div class="card ">
      <img src="assets/img/SB-admin.png" width="150px" style="witdth:30%">
      <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let user of searchuser">
        <h4><b>员工:{{user.username}}</b></h4>
        <p >职工号:{{user.empID}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool-card">
    <div class="card ">
      <img src="assets/img/tools.jpg" width="150px" style="witdth:30%">
      <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let tool of searchtool">
        <h4><b>tool:{{tool.tool}}</b></h4>
        <p>toolinfo:{{tool.toolmodel}}</p>
        <p >toolrfid:{{tool.rfidCode}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<br>

<form [formGroup]="toolusageform" (ngSubmit)="onToolUsage()">
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="form-group">
  <p *ngFor="let user of searchuser" formControlName="username">{{user.username}}</p>
  <p *ngFor="let tool of searchtool" formControlName="rfidCode">{{tool.rfidCode}}</p>
  <button type="submit" class=" btn col-lg-4 function" value="borrow">toolborrow</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you update your post with some code what you already have?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the formGroups `searchuserform` and `searchtoolform` after you recieve with your get call in the subscribe part.

Create a function which handles the formGroup, for example for searchuserform

```
SetSearchUserForm(data:any) {
  this.searchuserform = new FormGroup({
        // I assume that data which is received from your WEBAPI contains a key usernames and want to set this in your formControl 
        usernames: new FormControl(data.usernames, [<any>Validators.required, ...] })
}
```

and call this function in subscribe part of your GET

```
this.http.get('http://your_url')
        .subscribe(
            result => SetSearchUserForm(result),
            error => fnOnError(),
            () => fnDoAlways()
        );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if I use this way I will don't need use ngFor?

Comment: You could choose to use not ngFor. In code example in plunker I use an array for formControl. first formGroup contains single control which holds the array in a input. second example shows how to split in multiple input fields, when you use the second example don't forget to merge the values in an array back before you send it to the backend. code example: http://embed.plnkr.co/z8AzheJEhrAWJS06UY8T/.